# How can I check if the player is not colliding with an object? (JAVA)

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a prebuilt java game engine but I've rewritten the collision system to use both the player's position relative to the tiles as well as rectangles for collision. I need to be able to check if the player is not colliding with anything to allow the player to move again but in my method, I can only check if the player is colliding.

```
     protected void tileCollision() 
    {    
        int calledNumTimes = 0;
        AnimatedSprite player = findPlayer();
        Tile lastCollided;



        for(int i = 0; i < _sprites.size(); i++) 
        {
            calledNumTimes++;
            AnimatedSprite spr = _sprites.get(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < tileWithinRange.length; j++) 
            {
                Tile tile = tileWithinRange[j];

                if(tile != null && spr.collidesWith(tile.getBounds()))
                {     
                        lastCollided = tile;
                        player.setCollided(true);
                        calledNumTimes++;
                        if(!spr.hasMultBounds() && !tile.hasMultBounds()) 
                        { //tile and spr have only one bound
                            //spr.setBounds(16, spr.getBounds().x + 5, spr.getBounds().y);
                            if(tile.getTileBounds().intersects(player.getBounds()))
                            {
                                tileCollision(spr, tile, -1, -1);
                                System.out.println("colliding");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("nope");
                            }
                           // spr.setBounds(16, spr.getBounds().x - 5, spr.getBounds().y);
                        }
                } else  if(tile != null && !spr.collidesWith(tile.getBounds()))

                    player.setCollided(false);
                }
            } //end _tiles for loop
        } //end _sprites for loop
```

As of right now,

```
                            System.out.println("nope");
```

is never printed, so I can only check if the player is colliding without being able to check if he is not.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your code. When theres no intersection if(tile.getTileBounds().intersects(player.getBounds())) "else" gets called with System.out.println("nope");

Answer (score 0):

Extract 'til you drop  and the problem will be apparent:

```
 protected void tileCollision() 
 {    
    int calledNumTimes = 0;
    AnimatedSprite player = findPlayer();
    Tile lastCollided;



    for(int i = 0; i < _sprites.size(); i++) 
    {
        calledNumTimes++;
        AnimatedSprite spr = _sprites.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < tileWithinRange.length; j++) 
        {
            Tile tile = tileWithinRange[j];

            if(tile != null && spr.collidesWith(tile.getBounds()))
            {     
                    lastCollided = tile;
                    player.setCollided(true);
                    calledNumTimes++;
                    if(!spr.hasMultBounds() && !tile.hasMultBounds()) 
                    { //tile and spr have only one bound
                        //spr.setBounds(16, spr.getBounds().x + 5, spr.getBounds().y);
                        computeTilePlayerCollision(spr, tile, player);
                       // spr.setBounds(16, spr.getBounds().x - 5, spr.getBounds().y);
                    }
            } else  if(tile != null && !spr.collidesWith(tile.getBounds()))

                player.setCollided(false);
            }
        } //end _tiles for loop
    } //end _sprites for loop

private void computeTilePlayerCollision(AnimatedSpr spr, Tile tile, AnimatedSprite player) {
    if(tileCollidesWithPlayer(tile, player)) {
        reportCollision();
    } else {
        reportNonCollision();
    }
}

private boolean tileCollidesWithPlayer(Tile tile, AnimateSprite player) {
    tile.getTileBounds().intersects(player.getBounds())
}

private void reportCollision(AnimatedSprite spr, Tile tile) {
    tileCollision(spr, tile, -1, -1);
    System.out.println("colliding");
}

private void reportNonCollision(AnimatedSprite spr, Tile tile) {
    System.out.println("nope");
}
```

Continue this ad-absurdum until the bug is obvious as it has nowhere in the spaghetti to hide ;)